# Erro operadores de comparação javascript

Tags: javascript

Pessoal já fiz o teste aqui e essa váriavel retorna true, mesmo com os operandos sendo iguais, nesse caso era para retornar `false` e ir pular para o `else`.

```
function testar(){
    var isOk =  /[A-Z][a-zA-Z][^#&<>\"~;$^%{}?]{1,20}$/;
    var nome = "Francisco";




    if(nome == ""){
        console.log("coloque o nome ")
    }else  if (nome != isOk.test(nome)){
        console.log("nome errado amiguinho");
    } else {
        console.log("ok vá em frente");
    }


}
```

Comment: Teria como você ser mais claro?

Comment: O primeiro `if` que tem não faz sentido. O que você queria de facto testar ?

Comment: `isOk.text(nome)` irá te retornar ou `true`, ou `false`. Agora, a variável `nome` é uma string.
`true /*false?*/ != 'Francisco'`.
Logo ele vai te jogar sempre no "nome errado, amiguinho".

Comment: @isac o primeiro if até onde eu entendi é pra verificar se o campo foi preenchido (se o input for == "" (string vazia), peça para colocar o nome)

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo Mas tem em cima `var nome = "Francisco";`, o que faz nunca entrar no primeiro `if` . A menos que isso seja um "exemplo" e o nome seja lido de outro lado qualquer que não o que está na pergunta.

Comment: @Isac eu acredito que seja um exemplo, ele provavelmente só está testando a lógica antes de implementar, tanto que as "mensagens" nos `alert`s são como validação para o usuário. Provavelmente será algum tipo de jogo de adivinhar o nome.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o que você queira fazer aqui seja isso:

```js
    var isOk =  /[A-Z][a-zA-Z][^#&<>\"~;$^%{}?]{1,20}$/;
    var nome = prompt("Digite o nome:");

(function testar(){
    if(!nome) { //se não for digitado nada...
        console.log("coloque o nome ")
    }else  if (!isOk.test(nome)) { //se o nome NÃO bater com o regex...
        console.log("nome errado amiguinho");
    } else { //acertou!
        console.log("ok vá em frente");
    }
})();
```

Na linha `if(!nome)`, se a pessoa não digitar valor nenhum, o valor `""` é considerado `false`. O `!` irá inverter e tornar o mesmo `true`, e rodar o código, pedindo para que digite algo. Se preenchido qualquer valor dentro, a string preenchida vai valer como `true`, e ao ser invertida será `false`, pulando para o `else if`.

Na parte `else  if (!isOk.test(nome))`, o `test` irá retornar `true` se o nome digitado for validado pelo regex, e então invertido pela exclamação. Ou seja, se o nome NÃO for validado pelo regex, resposta errada. O ultimo `else` irá responder ao contrário do if anterior, ou seja, se o nome estiver correto.

Existem formas melhores de se fazer isso, mas editei seu código o mínimo possível para fazer ele funcional.